# Why is buffered_arange is faster than torch.arange in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I am studying the code for wav2vecv2, and they have written their own [function](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/129d8594ccdc6644be84dc249e16489e049f4bfd/fairseq/utils.py#L265) `buffered_arange` which has exactly the same functionality as `torch.arange`.

```py
def buffered_arange(max):
    if not hasattr(buffered_arange, "buf"):
        buffered_arange.buf = torch.LongTensor()
    if max > buffered_arange.buf.numel():
        buffered_arange.buf.resize_(max)
        torch.arange(max, out=buffered_arange.buf)
    return buffered_arange.buf[:max]
```

But it seems `buffered_arange` is much faster than `torch.arange` despite more operations than simply a single line of `torch.arange`

```py
>>>%%timeit
>>>buffered_arange(10)
1.19 µs ± 5.28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>>%%timeit
>>>torch.arange(10)
2.26 µs ± 8.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

May I know what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference here is that `buffered_arange` is actually "buffered", that is, it always uses the same tensor for every call of the function. That is, if you call `buffered_arange` with an upper limit that is less or equal all previous ones, you'll probably get a speed improvement as only a slice of an existing tensor is returned - if on the other hand the upper limit is larger in every subsequent call, the buffered tensor must be enlarged every time.

On the other hand `torch.arange` creates a new tensor at every call.